# jQuery animate. animated div is always on top. i need it behind another div

Tags: jquery, css, animation, html

I'm using jquery to animate a div that is hidden by default and when the user clicks a button it appears from the bottom and behind that button.

But when using animate() the animation always appear in front of the button (no matter the z-index). can i change that behaviour?

basically this is what i've got:

```
#div_btn {
background:inherit;
background-position:-111px 0px;
width:100px;
height:37px; 
float:left;
z-index: 1010;
}

#div_anim {
width:213px;
left: 67px;
top: 125px;
position: absolute;
height: 293px;
background: #e8a865;
display:block;
z-index:999;
}
```

the trigger for anim:

```
$("#div_anim").css("display", "block");
$("#div_anim").animate( {"opacity":"1.0", 
"top":"75px", "left":"23"}, "fast");
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found that I always have to set a position: value on any element I want to apply z-index to. While you have it set on #div_anim (position: absolute;) it appears there's no position set on #div_btn so I would start by adding a position there.

Comment: I tried setting absolute position for the other div as well. but the problem is still there. I wonder if this is expected for the jquery function. any suggestions?

Comment: can you add your markup too and I can try to reproduce the issue?